# How to get the filename if particular regexp is present in the file in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, format, filenames, cpan

In a directory containing many files, if a particular regexp (or format) was found in file, get that filename

Example :

1. if word "rama" is found in file called ramayana, print the filename "ramayana"
2. if a file contains a particualr format something like "(TEXT - NUMBERS)" in a file name  called table, print that filename table

in shell that was pretty easy,something like

#### grep "mytext" * | cut -d':' -f1 | uniq

but how to do it in perl

Suggest me if any particaular CPAN module helps for this

Thankss

Comment: File::Find, or File::Find::Rule.  The rest is just a matter of reading the POD for either one of those modules, and providing the necessary "wanted()" function (File::Find), or the necessary rules and actions (File::Find::Rule).  If you only care about one directory (not recursive depth), just opendir, readdir, open each file, etc.  You know...programming.

Comment: Hmm :) thanks for introducing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples sound way more complicated than your shell one-liner. This is equivalent to your one-liner in perl:

```
perl -nlwe 'if (/mytext/) { print $ARGV; close ARGV }' *
```

`-n` to open files and read content. `-l` to add newline to print (for convenience). And if the text is found, we close the file handle to avoid printing multiple matches. It will be opened again if more files are to be processed.

Comment: To be more precise, I have an array @list_code that contains over 100 elements. when i am trying to search them using this code,                       foreach $ele (@list_code) { while (<>) { if (/\Q$ele\E/) { print "$ARGV\n"; close ARGV; } } } the prompt went to wait mode (neither displaying output nor going to prompt) the intentional output should be like, 1st array element is found in these many files and its filenames. 2nd array element is found in these many files and its filenames. 3rd array element .. and so on!! Hope this time i was clear in my question

Comment: @user1228191 This one-liner is designed to check for one thing, not a list of things. It will work the same way your `grep` will, when executed in the shell. If you have further specifications, you should add them to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne 'END { print join("\n", sort keys %found)} if (/PATTERNTOMATCH/) {$found{$ARGV[0]}=1;}' *
```

My first attempt was :

```
perl -ne 'if (/PATTERNTOMATCH/) {print "$ARGV[0]\n";}' *
```

but that would print out multiple filenames if it matches more than once in a file. To stop showing the dupes I tried to use 'last' to break out of the implicit loop, but it didn't seem to work. So the top example, puts the filename into a hash whenever it finds a match (if (/PATTERNTOMATCH...) and then in the END block (which is at the beginning!), it prints the keys from the hash (to remove duplicate filenames).

It's a bit horrid I'm afraid. I'd stick with the CPAN module mentioned by DavidO above

Comment: Sorry for troubling you. actually i had an array that contain a list of words to be searched over files directory (sometimes recursive). but while i am trying to use while (<>) two times for different tasks in the same program , its getting into wait mode (neither displaying any error nor printing output), how to avoid that

Comment: I have an array @list_code that contains over 100 elements. when i am trying to search them like this foreach $ele (@list_code) { while (<>) { if (/\Q$ele\E/) { print "$ARGV\n"; close ARGV; } } } the prompt went to wait mode, which was slightly different, any idea!!

Comment: For the first ele loop, the <> operator is going through all the files. Once it gets into the 2nd loop, it has nothing left to read, so waits for standard input. I'm not sure how you'd 'reset' it to start again on the files, so maybe put the foreach inside the while loop (so that it looks for all elements in the first file, then all elements in the second file). I'm not sure if that breaks what you're trying to do though.

Comment: yea, you got my point, but how to reset it back is the question now!! that  "foreach solution" didn't work for my question

Comment: It will display all the filelist that array elements contain, which was not intended. The required output should be like, 1st array element is found in these many files and its filenames. 2nd array element is found in these many files and its filenames. 3rd array element .. and so on!! Hope this time i was clear in my question